# Rails pagination displaying wrong number of output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

In my rails application, I want to order `@students` by their latest assignment date. point to be noted that

> it's not necessary that every student should have an assignment on the
>   same date or something like that. That means any student can have
>   assignment at any date.

The code of my controller is:

```
@section = current_user.section
@students = @section.students.includes(:assignments).order('assignments.assignment_date ASC').paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
```

The problem is, in the view, there are sometimes 10 students in the list, sometimes 6 items etc. I mean random between 1 to 10. There should be some wrong in my logic. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**UPDATE:**

I found that there is nothing wrong with the pagination. The problem is, `@section.students.includes(:assignments)` fetching duplicate `student_id`  which are being eliminated.

Comment: On your view helper: you can pass your custom url with parameter to make sure the paginator is getting the right query.

Comment: Can you try by change the order of `order` and `paginate`  : `@students = @section.students.includes(:assignments).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('assignments.assignment_date ASC')`, not sure though.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, Thanks, but no luck! :(

Comment: What `@section.students.pluck(:id)` is returning ? Can you paste the result here?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, that's a huge array of ids. But I am assuring you that there is no duplicate id.

Comment: are you using 
<%= will_paginate @students %>
in views?

Comment: @VishnuAtrai, yes. I found that my problem is actually in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
@section = current_user.section
@students = @section.students.includes(:assignments).order('assignments.assignment_date ASC').paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this is basically the same.